# C++ Vectors: Function not viable + No matching function

Tags: c++, vector

So, it seems every time I try to compile, I am running into an issue involving

"error: no matching function for call to 'search_and_report'"

```
   while(name!="!")
   {
      label = "linear_search";
      search_and_report(names,n,name,label,linear_search);

      label = "binary_search";
      search_and_report(names,n,name,label,binary_search);

      cout << "Search for name: (! when done): ";
      getline(cin,name);
   }
```

And I suspect it is my initialization of the vector that is causing the problem.

```
{
   int n = 0;
   string label;
   string name;
   vector<string> names(n);

   // start program
   cout << "Enter a name (! when done): ";
   getline(cin,name);

   while(name!="!")
   {
      n++;
      names.push_back(name);
      cout << "Enter a name (! when done): ";
      getline(cin,name);
   }
```

I have been reading from this site:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm
and it says that I should be allowed to place my `"n"` in `push_back` to allow it to grow. But if I'm honest, I'm not sure I'm understanding vectors as well as I should.

*EDIT* As mentioned in the comments, I have removed the external code, and as asked, I will provide the function signature.

```
void search_and_report(std::vector<const string> names[], int n, string name, string label,
                       bool (*search)(vector<const string> names[], int n, string name,
                                      int &count))
```

Comment: Relevant for this error message include (1) declared function name versus function name used in call, (2) whether the function is declared at all in this scope, (3) types of actual arguments versus types of formal arguments. What's done somewhere else, e.g. in an initialization of a vector somewhere else, does not matter. Please do post a **complete but minimal example**, with the code here, not off-site.

Comment: What is the signature of the function `search_and_report`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, will do. Sorry, mind if I ask why posting off-site is not a good thing to do?

Comment: @ichramm, I can edit and add that now!

Comment: you need to change your functions to take `vector<string>` (probably by  const-reference)  , not `vector<const string>` and especially not `vector<const string>[]`

Comment: WRT posting code externally: links tend to go dead over time, so someone who finds this question in the future may find it useless.  If all of the relevant code is posted in the question, then someone who finds this question later will be able to understand the question and the answers in full.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Oh, makes sense. I'll make sure to do that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you've provided, the signature of the function `search_and_report` is:

```
void search_and_report(vector<const string> names[], int n, string name,
                       string label,
                       bool (*search)(vector<const string> names[], int n,
                                    string name, int &count));
```

The first argument is not a vector, is **array** of vectors.

Based on what I've read, you should change the function to take a `const std::vector<std::string>&` (see signatures of `binary_search` and `linear_search`).

Note: Using `std::vector<const string>` makes no sense because the vector handles all the memory allocation for the string objects it holds. I think you want to use `const std::vector<std::string>&` as I wrote above.

**Update:** About binary search.

If the vector is ordered, you can perform a binary search this way (pseudocode):

```
bool binary_search(vector, str, begin, end) {
    int m = (end + begin) / 2;

    if (vector[m] < str) {
        return binary_search(begin, m-1);
    }

    if (vector[m] > str) {
        return binary_search(m+1, end);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks.
Now I just need to fix my binary_search because it's not finding anything.

Comment: maybe it is because the search is not binary!

Comment: Just some notes: Binary search is useful only if the vector is ordered: You take the element at the middle and jump to the left or to the right depending on the value of the current element. Otherwise it will work just the linear search.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see what you mean. There's a sort function there. I guess I should check to see that it's working with the vector.

Comment: I update my answer with some pseudo-code, hope it helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101734/discussion-between-pacificfrost-and-ichramm).

Answer (score 1):

```
void search_and_report(vector<const string> names[], ...)
...
vector<string> names(n);
...
search_and_report(names,...);
```

You've declared `search_and_report` to take a pointer to an array of `vector<const string>`s, but you're passing it a `vector<string>`.  The compiler can't find an appropriate function to call because your types don't match.